# Regex to match comma separated value with last 3 digits

Tags: regex

I was trying to have the value as `456,987,214`.

But For me it is coming like without comma.

Here is my code, Did i mistake anything

```
const string price = "^\\d{3},\\d{3},\\d{3}$";
                string pricelist =  query.price.ToString();
                string price1 = "";
                if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(pricelist.ToString(), price))
                {
                     price1 = query.price.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: the input value is like `456987214` and you want is to output `456,987,214`?

Comment: What does this have to do with AngularJS?

Comment: Agree code looks like C# but tag only says angular

Comment: Are you making pricelist string from price string (regex)? Or, be more specific. Give examples of input/output etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed it, it is number what you intended to format why not using angular built-in formatting feature like: `{{price | number}}`

[**Online Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwomOkuk2DPCmtVGGMDs?p=preview)

If you want to format this with C# then you can format it using .Net built-in formatters like:

```cs
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
// outputs 1,234,567,890
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple Method:

Just pass your value like this ,

```
double value = double.Parse(query.price.ToString());
string price1= value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Output will be like **123,456,789**

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method: Just pass your value like this, then you will get the output as you want.

```
double value = double.Parse(query.price.ToString());
string price1= value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Output will be like `123,456,789`